# Zoomable And Draggable Line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

**I want to draw a chart which having zoomable and draggable property.**

[image: Chart View 1]

**After Zoom Those having child element Should show like below image.**

[image: Second View after zoom child element is showing]

I didn't find any Clue over it.

Comment: I dont know who downgraded this question,
If you dont know the answer dont do like that.

Comment: This is a good question i don't know why its down voted. upvote+

Comment: The question contains no code, it doesn't show how the OP is doing what he's doing, nor does it show any attempt at a solution. There are many many questions that demonstrate zooming and dragging in d3. When the OP researched them what was the issue that prevented him/her from using that information to implement a solution. In short, in what way do you feel the question **does** show research effort?

Comment: @RobertLongson So what you think i can not search that Zoom or drag

Comment: If you have common sense you should understand because i am adding a tag of D3 and my title contains zoom and drag both key word. If you dont know the answer that  Ok.
See i dont want code i want overall approach Which Cyril did for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the diagram you have posted there is no direct d3 laout to arrange nodes in this spiral manner. However if you know the place where you need to position a node then you can make of force layout.

Yes you have the dragging of nodes available the links will get updated accordingly. Attaching a fiddle you can improvise on this and add images to node. The data of the node should like this:

```
"nodes": [{
        "x": 30,// as i said you need to provide the x coordinate where to put the node
        "y": 30,
        fixed: true,//so that the force layout don't move it
        name: "Start", //text to be displayed 
        display: "none",// set this as none if you dont want the circle
        tx: 5, //x placement of text on node
        ty: -5 //y placement of text on node
    }, {
        "x": 200,
        "y": 30,
        fixed: true,
        name: "A"
    },
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/5p8vj2cn/3/).